# Excel: How to format a column graph so that it automatically adds new columns when new data is added?

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2010

A bit of background: I have a table which by using a combination of vlookup and index, goes through my main dataset and pulls out each row of data for a given month (in this case March). Each month will have a maximum of 15 entries, but may have less.

The image below is an example of the table for the month of March, which currently has 4 entries.

[image]

I want to create a column graph which is sourced from this table, that formats in a way such that if there is:

- 4 entries, it shows 4 evenly spaced columns
- 5 entries, it shows 5 evenly spaced columns
- etc...

However, when I create this graph using the two yellow highlighted columns of data, I get 4 columns (in the graph) squashed over to the left side, and a whole bunch of blank space, as seen below:

[image]

Is there a way that I can create a graph that looks like the graph on the left, and that will add in new columns automatically as data appears in the table, without looking like the graph on the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automatically updated your graph data ranges using VBA.

For example if your data range is in `columns A and B` of `Sheet2` and your graph is `Sheet1` you could use the following code:

```
Sub UpdateRange()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RngCount as Range

Set RngCount = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")
LastRow  = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngCount)

Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

Graph with old data:

[image]
[image]

After data was added and the macro was run:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, exactly what I was looking for. I'll adapt the code for my spreadsheet.

Comment: No worries, glad to help @BJJBA

Comment: Could I get some help interpreting the code so I can adapt it to my spreadsheet?

For example, in the line:
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 

Does the "A" mean the contents of the top left hand corner of the graph  (an "A"), or does in refer to column A?

Comment: Also, with the line:

Range("A1:B" & LastRow) - 

Does A1:B mean starting in Cell A1, and moving to B? ie. if I moved the input to Columns D & E, would I change this to D1:E?

Comment: It means that i counts all used rows in column A of sheet 2.

Comment: So if your data is in sheet 3 column C you would change it to: LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: You would change it to Range("D1:E" & LastRow), correct.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give that a go!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135331/discussion-between-bjj-ba-and-vba-pete).

Comment: my work security doesn't allow me to access chats :/

Comment: Damn, I'll post my question here then

Comment: Say I have data in columns B and D. I changed the code so that it says "Range("B1:D" & LastRow)". This works if I have nothing in C, but falls apart if I add data to C (which is what will happen when I apply it to my real problem). Is there a way to have the code just pick up columns B and D?

Comment: You have to set `Range("B1:D" & LastRow)` and remove column C in the `Select Data Source` of the graph. Once you set it up one time, it will be permanently removed as long as you use the macro to update.

Comment: Awesome! Last question (hopefully). Say the data is in Column A and B, but there is also other data further down the sheet in Columns A and B. Is there a way to set up the code so it only affects say the first 10 rows?

Comment: Hey Pete, the code works great when I start the data in A1 and go to A10, but it starts to fall apart if I go from say A7 to A17. Any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, if you start at A7 you need to add 6 because you are missing to count the first 6 cells: Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngCount) +6